# starting address of integer array pointing to itself?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The output of the programmer :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (){
 int A[3] = {1,2,3};
printf("%u %u %u ",&A,A,*A); 
return 0;
}
```

is :3216303812 3216303812 1

here &A and A is same that means address of a is same as the value of a  i.e A is pointing to itself. and *A means value stored at 3216303812 which is A itself as we know &A = A.. so where is the 1 coming from ?? how come *A = 1 ? Please help

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: ... but the one I voted for as a dupe isn't one.  Exuberant use of the return key got me.

Answer (score 5):

`A` is a pointer to the first *element* of the array, i.e. it's equivalent to `&A[0]`.

`&A` is a pointer to the *entire array*.

Of course these addresses have the same *value*, since the address of the first element of an array is the same as the address of the array. However they have different *types*: `A` yields a pointer to int, whereas `&A` is a pointer to an array of int.

Comment: Thanks Carl , actually i wanted to understand the memory arrangement for the same, As A is the starting address of the array, so ideally memory arrangement should have been something like , at 3216303812 ->1  (i,e *A), at 3216303816 -> 2(i.e *(A+1)) and at 3216303812 ->3 (i.e *(A+2)). But *A is equivalent to  *(3216303812) , and i am seeing at memory address 3216303812 we have A , because &A=3216303812 , and A is 3216303812 , so *A should be 3216303812. Please correct me where i am going wrong.

Comment: @user2588495: read the answer above again, carefully - understand that `A` and `&A` are different *types*, even though they have the same *value* (address).

Answer (score 0):

`A` means `&A[0]`, so `*A` is equivalent to value of first element in array, hence output is `1`.